# python / generic type hints for partial mapping specialization

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I have a question concerning type hints when using a partial specialization for a mapping.

See the example code below : the type `PairLeftRight` is a kind of `Dict[Side, Any]`.

The function `test_pair` will accept a specialized type : `PairLeftRight[MyClass]`.

I would like to be able to add type hints to this function, so that my IDE (pycharm) helps me by auto-completing the available methods in `MyClass``

Is is possible?

```
import typing
from enum import Enum

VT = typing.TypeVar('T')  # Any value type.

class Side(Enum):
    Left = "Left"
    Right = "Right"
Sides = [Side.Left, Side.Right]

class PairLeftRight(typing.Dict[Side, VT]):
    pass

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def hello(self):
        print("Hello " + self.name)

# Here, I want to speficy that the input is a PairleftRight[MyClass]
def test_pair(pair : PairLeftRight[MyClass]):
    for side in Sides:
        # Here I would like my IDE (pycharm) to help me by auto-completing
        # the available methods in `MyClass`
        pair[side].hello()

def test():
    a = PairLeftRight()
    a[Side.Left] = MyClass("Robert")
    a[Side.Right] = MyClass("Melissa")
    test_pair(a)

test()
```

Comment: `print(test_pair.__annotations__['pair'])` gives me `__main__.PairLeftRight[__main__.MyClass]` for your code, which means the class gets referred correctly within the function. Autocomplete from pycharm also links `hello()` as the first option for `pair[side].` with ctrl+space when I try it. What is your pycharm version?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I am using the latest pycharm under windows (pycharm 2017.3 #PC-173.4674.37 built on March 6th 2018).

Comment: I guess I am unlucky enough. Are you also under windows with the same version ?

Comment: Well, I also use pycharm 2017.3, my version is even a little older, even but I am on ubuntu. [Here is what it looks like for me when I press ctrl+space after typing the dot](https://imgur.com/a/J6s8f)

Comment: I guess pycharm just gave me the answer in a popup balloon. I am using python 3.5, and I think I need to update to 3.6... https://imgur.com/a/nfQuK

Comment: Well, I am glad you solved it. Kind of tricky, since [the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) was accepted for 3.5. I wonder why pycharm can't work it out on that version.

Comment: Well, no luck either: When updating to python 3.6, I still do not have the completion. This is probably a difference between the windows and linux version of pycharm